# Reviewing questions regarding help to solve a programming problem without prior attempt

Tags: discussion

I just recently received review access on stackoverflow, which I've tried to take advantage of. I've noticed a lot of questions request a solutions to a programming problem without any prior attempt and/or does not have any code to show. Not to point any specific fingers, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615005/how-to-sorting-date-time-in-string-array-php) could serve as an example.

My general sense from the overall community is that these kind of questions are not approved, however I don't know what kind of review response I should give. From my point of view they don't break the rules displayed in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and so I don't see how I could flag them as `Unsalvageable`; I have a heard time seeing how an edit could resolve it and they certainly are not OK.

How should I as a reviewer approach this?

Comment: Regarding that specific example, the comments indicate the asker does have code (that isn't working), and while they've provided example input, they haven't provided the expected output.  You could mark that one unsalvageable (though we really mean "could be salvaged, but only if the asker edits"...).  In general, if the question is clear, reasonably narrow, and any necessary inputs/outputs are provided, such questions are just fine.  You can always Skip if you aren't willing to hit Looks OK, or give Looks OK and downvote from outside the queue.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yeah, I was reviewing it before it had any comments but I see your point. How do you think I should flag it in that case?

Comment: Not sure I agree with the dupe here - looks like this question is specific to triage review, but the dupe seems to be about normal browsing and not reference triage really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General advice on when to use what:

- **Looks OK**: Only for questions that are worth an expert or other knowledgeable user attempting to answer (or find a duplicate using domain specific knowledge)
- **Requires editing**: Issues that need a kindly community member to fix up, but once a volunteer has assisted will end up looking OK. (E.g. formatting, spelling/grammar). These questions *will* end up getting sent to another queue patrolled by users who want to help with tweaks needed to bring borderline questions up to scratch. If they can't address it then it is wasting their time by using this option.
- **Unsalvageable**: The poster has dropped the ball. Something they've not included is fundamental to the question, or simply they haven't made sense. (Or worse). Only they can fix it, or possibly even they couldn't. Even if a kind volunteer fixed the formatting, language etc. then the question should still be closed. (Don't waste valuable editor time on something that's junk anyway)

So for your specific example I can see a bunch of minor things that somebody could edit, however the bigger picture seems to be that even after addressing those the question is still a poor question. The effort taken to fix the minor things is wasted if the question still should be closed and eventually deleted.

Comment: In the beginning I was quite liberal with the 'Requires editing' button, but I came to realise, as you say, that it means they only get pushed down the pipe. I am still a little bit uncertain _how_ to flag those questions (as in for what reason), but I guess that intuition comes from experience as well.