# What is the status of the improvement in the 'Help and Improve' queue?

Tags: support, help-improvement

One year ago, we had a discussion about [improvements in the Help & Improve Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue).

One [interesting Suggestion was by @davidism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287467/2441442):

> What's feeding this queue needs to be improved, and this queue needs a
>   feedback button: <kbd>No, this doesn't need improvement, it's just
>   bad</kbd>

On March 15, an employee marked this with ["status-planned"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/287467/revisions).

Since that is more than one year ago, what is the actual status of this improvement?

Comment: Just wait another 6-8 weeks. :p

Comment: I already waited for 55 weeks ;) I gived up this queue, because for 90 % of Questions, my action would be close vote.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt They've known about this problem since before the queue even went out into beta.  Clearly they have no interest in fixing the problem, especially considering that huge improvements could be made with virtually zero dev time.  If they were going to fix it, they'd have done it a *long* time ago, and at this point it's almost certainly too late to do much; the triage queue has become too trained in sending H&I crap.  It was a problem that needed to be solved immediately.

Comment: The triage and H&I queues are together so bad at ejecting craps questions, it seems they were a cynical means of playing lip service to site quality while allowing the same old garbage through unhindered.

Comment: I've tried to give as much guidance as possible to triage reviewers on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321002/168175 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316295/168175

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, [their implementation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387) of a "this is bad" button left a lot to be desired.

- It's not placed with the other actions.
- There's no guidance for it.
- It's a "Very Low Quality" flag, which has specific connotations that don't necessarily match things that don't belong in the queue.
- The flag often ends up disputed or declined, because it just sends it back to the triage queue which was broken enough to send it to the H&I queue to begin with.
- They don't seem to have addressed the first and more important point, which was the quality of question being put in the queue.  It should actually be a "close, needs info from op" flag.

I decided to look at the queue's [recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/history).

- Unlike other queues, there's no granularity about what actions were taken, only "edit" shows up on at least the first 10 pages.  Either there's no audit mechanism for seeing what gets ejected from the queue by the flag, or no one is using the flag.
- Instead of using the flag, token edits are being made to questions that remain low quality afterwards.  The reviews mostly edit for spelling, grammar, or formatting.  Nothing is being done to fundamentally improve the questions.
- There's no way to directly see what the review edit did, you have to click through to the normal, no permalink, diff page.

Most of the reviews I looked at that happened at least 24 hours ago gained no answers or upvotes for the question and the questions should have been closed instead.  This was just a short skim, I'd love to see some actual statistics about this.  Here are some recent reviews (not to call out reviewers, I think this is the queue's fault).

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/12091507 "question" doesn't demonstrate problem
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/12090361 homework code dump
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/12088451 added code highlighting to 8 characters
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/12088452 still has obvious errors, still links to code rather than including it
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/12084569 needs to read "how to ask" page
- etc.

I still feel totally uninspired every time I look in that queue, yet I'm editing to improve regular questions every day.  If they have improved the queue, they didn't make those improvements visible enough or effective enough to draw me back in.

Comment: The flag is not a review action, so it won't show up in the recent reviews list.

Comment: Why isn't it a review action? It ends the review for the user and removes the question from the queue.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295951/question-of-low-quality-link-in-help-and-improvement-review-queue/, which Shog commented on, so I'm tolerably sure that's right.

Comment: <Sarcasm>The H&I queue is very useful....as a robot detector. </Sarcasm>.The "reviewers" who make those token edits are often robo-reviewers in other queues too.

Comment: it looks like safer approach to "this is bad" questions in H&I is to open outside the queue and vote them down and close (flag to close for reviewers under 3K). After that, return to queue and Skip. What a mess

Comment: @gnat There is an easier way with a userscript, see [updated answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321504/3717023).

Answer (score 8):

> No, this doesn't need improvement, it's just bad

This was implemented in March 2015, a few days after the status-planned tag was added. Namely, the [VLQ flag was introduced in HIQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387), as a way to move questions that can't be improved in HIQ out of the queue.

I don't think the VLQ flag does enough, so I added other options with my  [Enhanced Review](https://stackapps.com/q/6621) userscript:

- Clicking on any close reason casts a close vote via the API and skips the item in review.
- Clicking "downvote" casts a downvote via the API but does not skip, so that one can downvote *and* close vote.

[image: HIQ]

This is only tested with 3K account, I don't know if it works for those between 2K and 3K.

Comment: LOL, it realy needed the screenshot, to notice it is even there!