# Do we have any stats on how often the skip button is pressed?

Tags: support, help-improvement, statistics

Do we have some statistic about the ratio the skip button is clicked in the "Help and Improvement" queue?

Just wondering if my ratio (which feels nearly 95%) is near the same as for other community members.

I asked some questions about the H&I queue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321503/what-is-the-status-of-the-improvement-in-the-help-and-improve-queue). Both are regarding, I always click skip.

Since nothing has improved, I am starting wondering how are the global stats in this queue? Am I the only person with a high skip ratio?

[image: skip]

Comment: And I want skip ratio for *all* queues please.

Comment: H&I is all about the skip. The ratio of finding something worth doing is *VERY* low.  That queue desperately needs some filtering...

Comment: Does 'not visiting the queue at all' count as skipping?

Comment: I tend to skip most "leave open" posts in the clove vote queue, because we have a limited amount of close votes and I want to use them all

Comment: If you use Skip a lot, that's good! It's a sign (not proof, but a sign) that you review with care.

Comment: @S.L.Barth , But the downside of skipping a lot is that you spend 20 seriously painful minutes attempting to read something into these posts, and don't actually accomplish anything.  And after that 20 minutes you start to worry about the future of humanity.  It is not good for one's health.

Comment: Don't feel bad about your skip ratio, at least your review queue doesn't say "You have made too many incorrect reviews... Come back on Apr 21 at 16:24 to continue reviewing." I should have skipped more..

Comment: @jhhoff02 the reason I feel bad has Stephen very good explained.

Comment: Yeah I struggle a lot with the H&I queue also. It feels like most everything I see in there should be closed, usually as broad or unclear. I've only ever done 5 items according to my stats.

Comment: @S.L.Barth If you're a new reviewer, then sure, skipping a lot is a sign of a good reviewer.  For someone with a decent amount of experience, it shouldn't be particularly high.  The review queues are *designed* to only show people items that they should be able to review.  If people are skipping a lot then it either means they're skipping posts that they were capable of reviewing (which is at least somewhat concerning) or it means people are being shown lots of reviews that they can't act on (which means that the queue is broken in some way).

Comment: @StephenRauch filter by tag would be nice, i could just watch out for [tag:c#] and wouldn't see all those [tag:javascript], [tag:php] or [tag:python] questions/answers I have no clue about anyway.

Comment: @Servy, you make a reasonable point, but there can be other reasons to skip reviews besides lacking experience or familiarity with the topic of a particular review item. Clearly the signal to noise ratio in H&I is heavily skewed towards noise, so we get several people listing their high skip percentages here. For myself, the high number of suggested edits I've skipped, for example, is mostly because my experience there has shown that it's significantly more likely for a bad edit to be approved than for a good one to be rejected. So I tend to focus on the dross and skip (most) other items.

Comment: @Bryan Note how both of the examples of reasons you've given for skipping lots of reviews are as a result of major underlying problems (in the one case, the inability of the queue to serve content meriting review at all, in the other a large portion of reviewers not reviewing posts properly).  Having a lot of reviews skipped isn't a sign of health; it's a sign that there's a problem.  The skipping itself isn't necessarily the problematic behavior, but it's a symptom of other problems, not a sign that things are going well.

Comment: @Servy, I agree completely. To be clear, I wasn't suggesting that the situation (or even my particular approach to reviewing) is ideal.

Comment: This is my experience too and most of the times it is because there is nothing to edit in fact, there is just missing stuff in the question that noone can provide except the OP so it should have been closed instead. Hence it would help if the two buttons where not only Edit or Skip, but also 'Recommend Deletion', as in Triage. I often open the question in another tab to Skip it in H&I but flag it to be closed in the other tab.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I threw together [a SEDE query to group the H&I reviews by result type](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/649287/help-improvement-reviews-by-result-type).  This was the output when I ran it just now:

```
84633    Edit
424982   Not Sure
```

Thus the total number of results is 509,615, which means that 83.4% of H&I reviews are skips.

While not quite as high as your 95% number, this still seems abnormally high to me.

For comparison, I also tried [this query on the Suggested Edit queue](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/649243/suggested-edit-reviews-by-result-type):

```
5533753   Approve
6         Delete
278177    Edit
2939416   Not Sure
1947101   Reject
33074     Reject and Edit
```

Here the total is 10,731,527, giving a much more reasonable 27.4% skip rate.

Disclaimer: both of these results are different than what is listed on the relevant [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats); I don't know if this is because of an error in my query, or some other problem that is non-obvious.

Comment: SEDE is updated every Sunday, and skips don't count in the number on the stats page as reviews.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Right, but after accounting for both the numbers are still a bit off.

Comment: All review type ids can be found btw [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291853/292385) if someone is wondering

Comment: What's more worrying to me is the number of approved suggested edits. In my experience only about 20% are valuable

Comment: @tomredfern I imagine the vast majority of those are formatting fixes, not content.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The point is that a fairly low percentage of suggested edits are actually appropriate presentation level changes.  You could spend a bit of time in the queue if you wanted to see how bad most of the edits actually are.

Answer (score 21):

[People](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346002/do-we-have-any-stats-on-how-often-the-skip-button-is-pressed?cb=1#comment459666_346002) asked for the statistics for *all* queues. Ask and ye shall receive.

[Query used to generate charts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/650140/review-queue-vote-type-breakdowns)

## Close Votes

[image]

## First Post

[image]

## Helper

[image]

## Late Answer

[image]

## Low Quality Posts

[image]

## Reopen Votes

[image]

## Suggested Edits

[image]

## Triage

[image]

Comment: Most of the skip events could be avoided with [some magic filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575)