# Can we increase the review audit ratio in Triage?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, triage

The Help & Improvement queue has some serious problems. We all know it is because reviewers in the Triage queue do not do the best job. Today I even got banned because of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346020/what-is-the-official-moderator-statement-about-low-quality-flags-in-hi).

Some other related questions from me about this serious problem:

- [We finally need more appropriate review actions in Help and Improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement)
- [What is the status of the improvement in the 'Help and Improve' queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321503/what-is-the-status-of-the-improvement-in-the-help-and-improve-queue)

In the end, all the time the answer is, it is the fault of Triage robo reviewers.

Currently the [skip rate is 83.4 %](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346054/2441442) in the Help & Improvement queue.

So I propose to have a higher occurrence of review audits in Triage. I think  one more **STOP! Look and Listen** could teach them to make better reviews.

Comment: I doubt this would help, as the audits for triage are going to be spam/offensive posts, and so are going to be among the few types of posts that your average Triage reviewer will actually mark as Unsalvageable.  The problem is that just your average old Unclear or Too Broad question isn't going to be an audit, and so won't catch people marking such posts as Needs Editing.  It's easier to just avoid the HI queue when looking for posts to spend time editing.

Comment: @Servy agree to some degree. How about audits where it is clear, they should be closed (lack mcve, asking for a tutorial/library etc).

Comment: Another proposed solution was to add a [review tutorial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/812149).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt see, that's not all that clear either. There's plenty of on topic questions that can stand without an mcve.

Comment: @Servy there are plenty of review audits in the close vote queue that aren't spam or offensive. Why not funnel some of those audits into triage?

Comment: I used to spend most of my review time in Triage since that felt like the place where reviewing could do the most good.  But I got frustrated by the paltry quota and the relatively poor quality of the audits.  I gave up reviewing quite a while ago.

Comment: @TinyGiant Because then the vast majority of the reviewers there would end up getting banned for not reviewing properly.

Comment: @Servy I'm still waiting for the part that is bad

Comment: @TinyGiant That SE doesn't care enough to implement it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> it is the fault of Triage robo reviewers

Not entirely. The root cause of the mess in H&I (according to [what I heard from users with >2k rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346020/what-is-the-official-moderator-statement-about-low-quality-flags-in-hi#comment459796_346020)) is that **well-intentioned reviewers are being misled into clicking <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> on Unsalvageable posts because the on-the-fly guidance is just wrong:**

> **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by the author<sup>*[lol no]*</sup> or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

Adding audits to counter that without fixing the guidance will only lead to review bans for users who are unaware that [they can know better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue), which will lead to frustration, which will lead to users boycotting Triage, which will result in ***another* completely nonfunctional review queue**.

Therefore, we need to get the answer to the following question and then have the SE team act accordingly instead of creating more audits:

## How difficult can it possibly be to modify a blurb that is displayed on only ONE place in the entire network?

Comment: Not sure how hard it is but [they know about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues).

Comment: I am not sure, if this is realy the root of the problem. (of course the wording could be better). Meta consensus is also linked before the quick infos. Mostly the questions that go into the I&H-Qeue are hard-off-topic. Editing it would be the same as asking a/multiple new complete different question(s) (sometimes on a different Q&A). If the intention of "Requires Editing" would be to make an unsalvageable post salvageable, then the person should ask, why we have an "unsalvageable" Button in first case, take a look at the linked FAQ and everything is fine. But as I said - not sure.

Comment: HEAR HEAR!!! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues#comment387623_332727

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I'm sure it is A problem. Not sure if it is ALL the problem. So statistics would help to understand better.

Comment: Indeed, I've got the impression that only outright spam warrants being marked as unsalvageable (same as for VLQ flags). ***Every*** bad question can be improved by the author.