# "Help and Improvement" is dead, can we please let it die

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-improvement

After going through the H&I queue today, I estimate that at least 90% of the questions there are irredeemable trash that could best be helped and/or improved by destroying them with the heat of a thousand stars.

[This issue was brought up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue/291919#291919) two and a half years ago [and nothing has been done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291741/is-the-help-and-improvement-queue-just-bad-question-purgatory).

Given this, can we just nuke that queue (and any and all options that send things into it) since it literally does nothing except waste everybody's time?

Comment: Having a strike of rage won't help them go faster, you also could have learn to control your emotions...in a reasonable time frame ;) more seriously, there are plenty of things that takes too much time. Have they been forgotten ? or under a pile of 300 other dev demands ? Probably the second one

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Two and a half YEARS.

Comment: I am sure it was just this post that they where waiting on for something to be done..... Or maybe posts that cause debates about the rantiness of a post do nothing more then annoy the devs and users about something that is already a known issue.

Comment: I had [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357470/changes-to-requires-editing-button-in-the-triage-queue) feature request for changes to "Requires Editing" button and re-purposing the H&I queue but it mistakenly closed as duplicate.

Comment: Two and half years is [standard time for being ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252562/can-we-please-block-questions-that-contain-nothing-but-a-url-in-the-title), don’t take it personally :)

Comment: @IanKemp I'm a hundred % sure it could benefits the site and improve users experience. It's like other common sens things and improvements that haven't been done. Seen many... the dev team obviously NEVER been asked to work on these, they probably been asked to work on NEW features. Frustrating, but SO is still extremely useful, so why brother ?

Comment: You must be wearing some seriously strong rose-colored glasses if you only see 90% :)

Comment: How else could you do a "user administered" site better without some filtering process? How would you improve the current one? I'm kinda blown away by how well the community takes care of / helps people learn coding.

Comment: _is dead_ and _let it die_ seem contradictory to me

Comment: Note: [The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/q/4486/29529) userscript/extension adds a normal "close" link under questions in the H&I queue (along with many other changes/improvements). This at least allows you to vote-to-close questions without needing to open the question page.

Comment: @Makyen That's great - what would be even better is if Stack Overflow stopped throwing dev effort at doomed-to-fail idiocy like documentation, and spent it on these very necessary improvements. For christ's sake, how many other tech companies could go more than two years without fixing simple issues and still be in business?

Comment: @Clive I'm not taking it personally, I am just absolutely flabbergasted how a so-called tech company will literally do nothing about simple feature requests, while wasting time on things like documentation that nobody ever wanted or needed, and now has to be undone. It smacks of gross incompetence at the highest levels of management.

Comment: @IanKemp, While I'm not nearly as vehement about this as you are, I completely understand, [and share](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-qa-teamdag-product-development-priorities?noredirect=1#comment499849_354125), your frustration at the years-long lack of any movement in this area, particularly when there are things (e.g. the mere changing of the text describing "Requires Editing") which would significantly help and would take a very small amount of developer time.

Comment: "How many other tech companies could go more than two years without fixing simple issues"... Are we living in the same universe? Start by looking at Microsoft and Apple, then have a quick peek in the Firefox bugzilla and the Ubuntu issue tracker.

Comment: This would mean removing triage (yay) and adding questions back into the lqprq

Comment: @Makyen why do you need a "Close" button there when you have "question is very low quality" link/button? They just need to move it next to the "Skip" and "Edit" buttons (which will never happen, probably).

Comment: @Dmitry, Because all "question is very low quality" does is flag it as Very Low Quality, causing it to go back to the Triage Review Queue, where it was *already* incorrectly identified as "Requires Editing". Voting to close the question puts it in the Close Vote (CV) Review Queue, where it might actually get closed. The CV Review Queue is where the question would have gone if the people in Triage correctly identified it as "Unsalvageable" (i.e. that the editing required must be done by the OP). For reference on what happens in the queues see: [this meta post](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659)

Comment: @Makyen Ah, I thought it was sent to the LQP for deletion. That is very misleading (like the rest of the community mod tools :-)). At first I was flagging questions in H&I queue but then I saw the "question is very low quality" link so I started using that. I'll continue flagging now. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Dmitry No problem. On SO, a VLQ flag on a question puts it in Triage (all other sites it goes into LQP). Yeah, it's a potential loop [Triage]➞ *Requires Editing* ➞[Help & Improvement]➞ *Very Low Qualify* ➞[Triage]➞ *Requires Editing* ➞[Help & Improvement]➞… This, combined with the misleading description of "Requires Editing" results in a good number of questions stuck in the loop. Voting/flagging to close the question *should* get it out of the loop and into the correct queue (Close-Vote). In addition to fixing the description of "Requires Editing", H&I really needs a close-vote/flag ability.

Comment: Aren't you more then a bit hostile and assuming malice of intent? it dilutes what you want and attracts downvotes.

Comment: @Magisch The carrot hasn't worked so far, so now it's time to try the stick. And I'm not particularly assuming malice, more incompetence (which is just as bad, mind you).

Answer (score 28):

Please don't let it die. Improve it instead.

The community has proposed many changes, one including a [simple change to a wrong text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing), which have been <strike>ignored</strike> neglected.

I can definitely see some value in the queue, if only salvageable posts would be enqueued.

And please don't ignore [our suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help-improvement+or+triage+feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined) anymore :) The system in its current state [is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346002/do-we-have-any-stats-on-how-often-the-skip-button-is-pressed).

Comment: I would love for it to be fixed. Unfortunately SO management has shown they don't care about fixing it, so they might as well just remove it. Although I feel like such a request is probably well beyond their capabilities too.

Comment: About "simple change to a wrong text" - the sad-funny thing is that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue#answer-295674) official FAQ exists which clearly states: _**Do not** choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author_. But they still did not change the text on the "Requires Editing" button.

Comment: No one is ignoring anything on purpose whatsoever. It's just the fact that there are plenty of other things that takes too much time. Most of them less important? Maybe. Probably. Most likely. Things do not work irl as You think they do. There are at least 5-10 tasks that slip through the meta and get a hell of a lot of upvotes nowadays, therefore ending up on the task queue. Not saying they aren't important. No. They all are. And we'd all want them to be eventually applied. Every improvement is good. Always. Thumbs up. Five stars. Amen.
But frankly, an approach like that is just sad...

Comment: @Skipper the time argument *usually* makes sense, but doesn't make the slightest bit of sense in this case. The majority of the problems with this queue quite possibly come from a *single incorrect sentence* of copy that explicitly instructs Triage reviewers to use the "Requires Editing" button in a pointless and destructive way that completely ruins the entire system. Multiple users, mods, and staff members have written lengthy Meta posts about this. The vast effort already wasted discussing this problem hugely outweighs any conceivable cost of changing *one damn sentence of copy*.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe "Triage" should be tweaked: now "Requires editing" is very general and mentions "edits by the author or others". But sometimes only the author can reasonably add the missing information so there is no use pushing it into the "help and improvement" queue.

So for "Requires editing", make it more clear that this means that the "others" have enough information to be able to improve the question. Plus that it means that the question will be pushed into the H&I queue.
And for "Unsalvageable", make it clear that only the author can salvage it. This is probably the same as an "unclear what you are asking" close vote.

Comment: If you see [Christian Gollhardt's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360011/603977), this was [proposed quite some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing).