# Are there statistics for "help and improvement"?

Tags: discussion, help-improvement

While writing [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372360/1531124) (where I express my frustration that the "help and improvement" queue seems to almost only consist of low-quality questions that could, if at all, only be improved by the original questioner), I started wondering: are there statistics somewhere?

As in:

- How many questions go into that queue?
- How many entries in the queue get skipped, or classified as "low quality"?
- How many questions get edited?
- Most importantly: how many questions get edited and *then*, later on result in question upvotes, and helpful (upvoted) answers?

In other words: does "help and improvement" really, significantly help and improve the quality of the community? Or is more like a nice idea that fails in real world?

(I often think: the only action that would actually *help* the OP is a distinct comment explaining the deficiencies of his input. But well, that is not the purpose of that queue. It asks to EDIT or SKIP, or re-classify.)

Comment: One statistic I'm interested in, is how many questions go from H&I -> VLQ flag -> triage queue, requires editing -> back to H&I (the H&I infinite loop)

Comment: It seems triage is (still?) the true root of the problem there, referring to Tim Post's answer on the linked thread. If that doesn't function properly then H&I has not a chance to function properly. Which is a shame because the queue would be a good tool for people who want to help out.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346002/do-we-have-any-stats-on-how-often-the-skip-button-is-pressed

Comment: Originally H&I _did_ require a comment. Since then, the requirements have been loosened tremendously, and now even the most superficial edit counts as a review. I trust that the H&I reviewers mean well, but I'm not convinced that these reviews genuinely help our new users. I'd rather see them take some time to write comments, that explain to new users how the site works.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks. I have to admit: I am tremendously surprised that this community seems to engage in activities for the sake of activity, without empiric evidence of being effective. It is only one step from there to "ok, then lets click through that queue, and make a simple update here or there" and collect that last missing steward badge...