# Why was I suspended from reviewing for selecting "Requires Editing" in Triage?

Tags: support, faq, review-queues, triage, review-suspension

I got suspended from reviewing without even noticing why, since there is no obvious link to http://stackoverflow.com/review

On the review page, I read:

> Your review on [triage/23957671](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23957671) wasn't helpful.
>
> "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead.
>
> Come back in 3 days to continue reviewing.

I learned it the hard way, that incorrectly tagging something is apparently more severe than wrongly flagging issues.

But the surprising point is actually something else: The majority vote was *Requires Editing* in the first round, which is in line with the policy that you should not be too hard to new users.

> [image: screenshot of review outcome]

Apparently, two other users have been voting to close the question as too broad afterwards and overruled the majority decision. This is what I do not understand - How come that 3x **Requires Editing**, 1x **Looks OK**, and 3x **Unsalvageable** (the "Mark" was one of the 3 close votes) adds up to **Unsalvageable**?

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225)

Comment: What kind of edit do you think would salvage that question?

Comment: My question is not about the specific question, my question is why about the logic of why I am getting banned.

Comment: If ten reviewers choose the same decision, it can still be wrong. Choosing "Requires Editing" sends the question to the Help and Improvement queue. What's the point of sending it there when no edit can help the question?

Comment: The "why" is choosing "requires editing" when is blatantly a wrong option. Presumably a mod went through your review history and discovered more of these choices. The ban is simply to make you aware of this.

Comment: That the majority chose wrongly only speaks badly of the majority (or of the user interface, in any case). It doesn't mean that the majority is right.

Comment: @yivi: I think there is no such a thing like "blatantly wrong" during review, if it is not spam, and the question seems valid. Reviewing is a very subjective thing.

Comment: You see? That's the reason the ban was necessary. You need to learn that that's not the way review works. This is an opportunity.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) may be helpful in the future for Triage. [This other guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) is useful for First Posts and Late Answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to review posts in the Triage queue. Please do not be disheartened by a review suspension, as it is the least drastic action that moderators can take to bring an issue privately to your attention without sending an official moderator message or account-level suspension.

While reviewing posts in the Triage queue, one of the options you are presented with is <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>. Unfortunately, most of the time reviewers misunderstand what this action is for (e.g. [q1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895/584192), [q2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319128/584192), [q3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/584192), [q4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372485/584192)), and what happens next if three reviewers pick this option in Triage.

If you expand the review guidance text, you can read that "Requires Editing" should be taken if ***you can (edit to) improve*** the question to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

[image]

However, if a post in Triage is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and therefore no amount of editing by you or fellow reviewers can make this on-topic, please do not select <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> - because this post will then be pushed into the "Help and Improvement" review queue, where it will be in limbo because **no other reviewer** will be able to edit the post to become on-topic for this site!

This makes more work for the community now because, firstly, the post wasn't closed in Triage with the "Unsalvageable > Should be closed..." option, and secondly, more users encounter another Help and Improvement review they cannot do anything about other than to take extra steps to click the permalink to open the question in another window and then manually vote to close.

You may find this [guide for the options in Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/584192) useful, as it explains what you should be looking out for before you select the best course of action.

---

In this [particular Triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23957671) you participated in, because three reviewers picked "Requires Editing" over choosing to close with the "Unsalvageable" option, subsequently a [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/23959685) review was generated, which I came across and closed it before investigating which reviewers selected the incorrect option in Triage.

Do not worry about this review mistake - I agree some review queues can be confusing and we are here to help and guide each other to make this site better one action at a time. As I can see that you are genuinely sincere in wanting to learn what went wrong with the review, I have now lifted the temporary review suspension since it has served its purpose to inform.

---

#### See also [Answer Part 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393128/584192), and [Feature request to fix Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/584192), then [come join us in chat to discuss reviewing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews).