# Review ban process is very cruel

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, review-suspension

As you know there is a review ban for wrong decisions. For example, when I visited back after some hours to start the review again I was faced with this message:

> Your review on [triage/24383821](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24383821) wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing"
>   should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to
>   edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is
>   unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please
>   flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see
>   [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148). Come back on Nov 24 at 5:27 to
>   continue reviewing.

Almost **next month** I will be able to review again, but for what? A wrong decision ban for a month? Who decided this length? Will this period will be shortened when a developer has great reviews on the past? **NO**.

You're punishing people for the bad review, but there is no reward for good reviews. At least decrease these periods or give a sign that warns a user that if you're not careful enough you will be banned (not that tricky one). There is no notification, email, etc to inform the user about why and how they banned.

This whole process makes me sad and actually, I think I won't review again despite this behavior.

**I never said it was my first and only bad review, but there is no learning, there is just punishing.**

Comment: The question is...why are you reviewing?  The reward is to make the site a better place.  Unfortunately, there are badges tied to the activity, so the process will be gamed so people can get the badge, which is actively detrimental to cleaning up the junk.

Comment: *"I think I won't review again despite this behavior."* -- Just stop and think about why it's bad for a month and come back later.

Comment: Sorry, with your track record you have to work doubly hard to prove you can be trusted to review properly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing it for fun, but...it has a purpose.  A purpose you're not fulfilling.  Bad reviews are worse than just leaving things alone, because it means someone else has to come along behind you and clean up the mess.  People are happy to do so every now and then, as it does take learning to figure it out.  But a sustained pattern just adds more work; you're making messes now, instead of cleaning them up.

Comment: "I think I won't review again despite this behavior." - not exactly clear what that part is trying to convey - "won't do X despite Y" usually used when Y is some sort of reward/encouragement... It's fine if you enjoy punishments, but the rest of the post does not seem to align with that...

Comment: @fbueckert I mean I am not regular reviewer I just do it in my free time and reached that point and it is huge progress but you people charge me for a poor review. that's not true.

Comment: "***...but there is no learning, there is just punishing***"? Did you click on [the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148) in the review suspension message and read my answer there? Also, those who have previously read and acknowledge my answer had their review suspension lifted early. Isn't that fair enough?

Comment: @SamuelLiew thumbs up

Comment: Just for clarification, after reviewing your own review . Do you understand the ban and the duration? Or even with your ban history you find it unfair?

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes I know the reason for my ban, but still duration isn't fair.
you know when a reviewer doesn't have bad reviews lately, then you should consider it in your algorithm.

Comment: doesn't have bad reviews lately? You just didn't get caught! https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24383800.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to understand that "requires editing" is for questions that are salvageable.

Comment: @Payam on a site like Stack, most, if not all you do is tracked and a lot of it, findable if you know how. Don't say stuff that can be verrified to be false. It just detracts from your argument

Comment: @DragandDrop I know, I mean not me other users that may have the same situation. 
I am not a native English speaker

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, it's not clear

Answer (score 30):

### No one gets banned for 1 month without previous history.

(It's just that the ban message usually only displays the most recent incorrect review, both because there's a length limit and because that's the information that is most readily available.)

I checked your ban history (which only moderators can see), and this is the seventh time you've been banned from reviews this year. Here's the history. You'll notice that the suspension time globally increases because it seems that you're not learning from your previous mistakes:

```
15 hours ago    user has been banned from review    Your review on triage/24383821 wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148.
duration = 32 days
Sep 19  user has been banned from review    You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24089429.
duration = 16 days  (show ip)
Apr 29  user has been banned from review    You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22878336.
duration = 32 days  (show ip)
Apr 11  user has been banned from review    You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22721705.
duration = 16 days  (show ip)
Mar 6   user has been banned from review    You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22384250.
duration = 8 days   (show ip)
Feb 21  user has been banned from review    You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22266558.
duration = 4 days   (show ip)
Feb 10  user has been banned from review    You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22165473.
duration = 2 days
```

Some of these bans were imposed manually by moderators, while others were automatically imposed by the system due to failed [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work). In both cases, a "twice the duration" algorithm is applied to determine the ban length. Standard practice is to escalate the duration of back-to-back bans. After you returned from a 32-day ban in April, you seemed to be doing a bit better, so you were cut some slack on the length of the next ban. So it went from 16, to 32, then 16, 32... and the moderator that issued that last ban was careful to check your previous history and decided to issue a long ban.

Note that while we don't typically make review histories public, I decided to reveal this here because the question wasn't stating all the facts prior to editing.

---

While you're banned from reviewing, take some time to [review our detailed guidance on reviewing Late Answers and First Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts). We also have [a guide for the Triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue). Please ask follow-up and clarification questions here on Meta, if necessary, to improve your reviewing skills. **Bans aren't meant to be punitive; they're meant to be educational (and to put a temporary stop to unhelpful reviews).**

Comment: Actually, this history shows how cruel it is, basically, it's like an exam which kick you out without showing your paper.

Comment: bad reviews degrade the site quality. Moderators / automatic audits are here to warn users. You've been warned a lot of times already, with reasonable ban times at start.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad Reviewing means improving content, not making it worse. How is stopping you from doing something that you're not good at and that you don't enjoy cruel?

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad You can describe it however you want, but the fact is that if you're giving out reviews that hurt the overall quality of the site then i don't see any reason to keep accepting your reviews.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you should make public this records for transpanacy!

Comment: no. I'm making your records public because you seemed to imply there's some sort of injustice here. But you kept making incorrect reviews, and the system (and moderators) blocked you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I mean make it a feature

Comment: no, we're not giving this information away to non-moderators. We don't want everyone to see everyone previous "faults" exposed. Unless someone asks for their _own_ case.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad you are welcome to post it as separate "feature-request" (also SE can't even make "show all my deleted posts" … so I'd not hold my breath for that feature)

Comment: Nah, I’m sure which ones are manual and which were automatic even with some of the bans having been done by ex-moderators :-D

Comment: *"...until someone decided to cut you some slack by dividing it by 2..."* Technically, no. That was an automatic ban issued upon failure of a review audit, so there wasn't a person involved. And the reason the ban duration is divided by 2 is because of the elapsed time between previous ban and this failure. April to September is almost 6 months, so there's some degree of forgiveness built into the system already.

Comment: Cody, thanks for making this answer more accurate. No wonder why SO site cost millions of $$ to create.

Comment: The logic behind the ban-duration is interesting. The idea is not bad, to increase ban times, but doubling them does not seem too helpful to teach people how to properly review (even if there is "some degree of forgiveness") since it is a punishment after all, not some positive feedback (which is much more powerful).

Comment: @B--rian - The length of the ban was only doubled due to the user not improving.  Besides only a few of review bans were manually issued by a moderator