# Getting banned from review

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

As per @Samuel Liew guide, it seems that I should exposed the same problem issued on [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me).

In my case, on [this triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24418414) question, I consider as `Requires Editing` because the user should edit it in order to bring some more additional data. After the reading of the [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me), I understood that my point of view was wrong.

I will not consider if it is fair or not fair the banning. Rules should be there. My point is that, in my case, at least, I am trying to collaborate with SO just because I like programming but I am not related to. So I think that I can collaborate in this way, as the same way I am collaborating on Tcl/tk News or Wikipedia.

Just banning people without any previous advice (at least on my case), will not be on the interest of SO if they are interested to keep some reviewers.

I think that, maybe, the same time it is taking to banned one guy can be used to give a warning, expose how the things works and done!

The normal feeling on any banning is that "you are making things wrong".

I will wait for my ban period, but I think that it will be more constructive to warn the people better than to ban.

Comment: *"Just banning people without any previous advice (at least on my case), will not be on the interest of SO if they are interested to keep some reviewers."* ... their/our first interest in this subject is to prevent incorrect reviews requiring others to clean that up. After that we can think about keeping reviewers.

Comment: This is not a discussion though, it is venting frustration. There is no tag for that, with good reason. If you want to discuss something, then do so. How about: ways that can be better communicated with you. You're right, not getting a heads up sucks. But how can it that be done better? Before you start to throw out wild ideas do keep in mind: there are thousands and thousands of people using the site, there are only a handful of people who would be capable to directly communicate with any of them.

Comment: @Gimby, it is not a discussion. In fact, I try to remove the tag before publishing and the system didn´t allow me. I am not throwing wild ideas (IMPO), I don´t know how many people we are as users and reviewers. There should be thousands and thousands of users daily but I don´t know if there are thousands and thousands of reviewers. I didn´t say that I was not wrong, in fact I accepted it. I supposed that moderators decide to use this system as per their experience, I was just wondering if a more constructive way was discarded.

Comment: *without any previous advice* At the top of the Triage queue, there is the sentence "We need your [help separating questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) into categories." The phrase "help separating questions" is a link to [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/215552). There is a (more) link which expands to show what each of the buttons mean. We've asked to get those updated. At the bottom there's yet another link to the same question. I'm not sure how much more one can expect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The review suspension ***is*** the warning, since there is no better way we can privately get your attention specifically for reviews only. The alternative is an [account-wide suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) which is reserved for more serious issues, and email will be sent to you while you are prevented from doing anything on the site.

Since you have read and understood the linked post and know what "Requires Editing" is for now, I've lifted the review suspension early.