# Asking for an early review-ban lift

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

I’m writing this post after reading a suggestion, in the comments of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me), by Samuel Liew.

**This is the Suspension Message I got:**

> Your review on [triage/24428646](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24428646) wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148.
>   Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

**This is the screenshot of my review:**

> [image]

**The reason why I selected “Requires Editing”** for that question is that I thought it could do with correcting of some spelling mistakes and sentence repetition, but also because the user should add some of their code or general approaches in tackling that issue.

I'd like to write it here explicitly that I now understand that the Requires Editing is not referring to an Edit that the OP can make, but the rest of the community of reviewers.

**I have to admit** that all this time I’ve been reviewing the Triage queues thinking that ‘Requires Editing’ included editing that can be done by the user themselves. It took this ban and reading similar posts here on meta to help me understand how mistaken I was about this*. I have received a 7-day ban, and compared to my activity in total and how frequently I check the queues, it’s not something that I can’t just wait out. But living my life with a “Josef K.” syndrome would make these 7 days really uncomfortable. I hope that my understanding of how to use these review options now is enough to grant me an early ban lift.

On a side note, seeing other threads with various time bans, it makes me wonder whether this was my first ban, or whether I was issued other bans for smaller amounts of time that I completely missed. This was the first time that I explicitly received such a warning.

Comment: The fact that this problem still pops up so regularly and the powers that be still haven't bothered to put out a fix that should just amount to changing a few strings continues to boggle my mind.

Comment: I was told [it was fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues), @John... It *does* now say, "for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing".

Comment: @CodyGray That's only visible if you click the "more" link, and isn't at all clear that "you" specifically means "not the OP." The fact that Shog's answer in that thread is a year and a half old and this is still happening on a regular basis should prove that it wasn't an adequate fix.

Comment: @CodyGray Would it not be better for it to say "for questions that _another reviewer_ can make clear ..." ? Then it would at least be clear that it is a reviewer that has to do it (albeit in another queue). Assuming they read the text of course.

Comment: Congratulations, your temporary review suspension is now lifted.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thank you very much, I really appreciate that!

Answer (score -16):

Take the 7 days off and answer questions or do something not related to SO. The suspensions are there for a reason and if you've learned something from it then they are doing their job.

Your understanding of the "Requires Editing" in the triage queue is a common one and quite a few people fall "victim" of misunderstanding it.

Comment: hopefully no part of my post reads as "this is unfair/wrong/stupid/etc". I understand the reason behind it now. That said I've seen people in my situation asking for the same thing and getting the lift. I hope for the same, for reasons that I already explained.

Comment: The fact that it's a common confusion suggests that the option should be renamed to something like "requires editing doable by the community" or "only requires editing".  I expect the enhancement will be done in the standard 6 to 8 years.

Comment: @SecurityHound That's not the purpose of the Triage queue. It's meant to be a rapid evaluation of the post into buckets, that's it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - nevermind.  Looking at the guidance it's clear what the correct choice should have been

Comment: @DanNeely Perhaps something to the effect of "Needs formatting and/or cosmetic edit"? To make it distinct from "needs an edit that adds more information", since "edit" alone can mean both.

Comment: @VLAZ I think that would still miss the point that the author wouldn't be involved in the process and only reviewers would be responsible for the formatting/cosmetic edit

Comment: I chose to upvote your answer solely on the first paragraph. Sentimentalism aside, it is valid advice. It is something that I've said to myself many times because I tend to take things too personally, I tend to care more than I should about other people's opinion of me and I tend to overthink things when It comes to correcting my mistakes. Some times I simply let things go, your comment serves as a reminder that I should do this more often. Thank you!

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I would disagree there. When a question is missing crucial information and the reviewer chooses "needs cosmetic edits", then this option is wrong independent of who performs the cosmetic edits.