# Triage review audit failed - normal question flagged as spam?

Tags: discussion, specific-audit

I'd like to know if someone can explain in what way I failed [this triage audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24588987). I am willing to learn, but I don't see any problem with this question myself.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is at least a second question with the exact same content (deleted by a moderator). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809760/stop-form-from-submitted-twice-on-multi-step-form-js. In general I agree with you that the question looks fine on it's own.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Still, a reviewer cannot know this and the audit fail seems wrong in this case. Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Wait here and see if a moderator steps in to explain what really happened. When tomorrow noone has helped, you could also flag your post here for moderator attention. When this review did not get you banned, there is not much a moderator can do anyway (besides giving an explanation).

Comment: Thanks for your help, yea it blocked me from reviewing. WIll do as you said and wait first

Comment: So I flagged this a few days ago for moderator intervention and am still blocked wrongfully, that kinda sucks :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24588987), as it was presented to you in the review queues, is not spam. You should be forgiven for not flagging it as being spam.

However, **your review was nevertheless incorrect**, because the post did *not* look OK. It was not self-contained; it did not provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

You should have instead marked that question as "unsalvageable", because the only person who could edit it into shape is the original asker.

Note that you have been told this on multiple occasions as the message for previous review suspensions:

> "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148).

That, taken with the fact that review suspensions are *never* given for a single failed review, is why I am disinclined to lift your review suspension this time.

As examples of other recent reviews that you conducted which were incorrect:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24588868 (No explanation for "not working", or what problem the asker is seeking to solve. This did not look OK. You should have chosen "unsalvageable"—yes, other reviewers got that wrong, too. That's no excuse.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24588732 (Clearly doesn't look OK. The text on the top and the bottom are *identical*. This is someone trying to get around a quality filter. The system is telling them that they need to explain their problem better, and it's right. The quality filter is dumb enough to be fooled by copy-pasted text, but you shouldn't be.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24587858 (Do you have any idea what this person is asking? If you do, you should have said that the question required editing. If, like me, you have no clue, you should have said it was unsalvageable.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24588116 (Again with the "doesn't work". There's no clear problem statement. The code isn't even properly formatted, so the question is not readable. This *definitely* doesn't look OK.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24588073 (Inappropriately formatted. Blockquote formatting is being used for things that are not quotes. Code appears as an image, rather than text. Not to mention, once again, there is absolutely no problem statement or question. This definitely doesn't look OK.)

Those are just taken from your 9 most recent reviews. You've got about a success rate of <50% currently.

While you wait out your review suspension, I would encourage you to read: [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the elaborate answer, I'll try to educate myself