# Improbable answer in audit: the answer seemed unrelated to the question

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I just failed review audit https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25514113. In this question OP was attempting to run Qt Creator. The answer suggested installing a package which looked to be entirely unrelated (`opencv-python-headless`), without explanation. As it turns out this works, and the correct response on my part would have been to give a positive response.

However there was no way for me to know that; without context, it looks like some sort of spam which posts answers suggesting the installation of random packages! As such I don't think this is an appropriate audit.

---

Version of answer at review time (currently much more plausible after Cody's edit):

> If you are on Mac, go to the terminal and paste the following,
>         `pip3 install opencv-python-headless` 
>   *It might solve your problem!!
>   Cheers!!

Comment: "Skip" is always good choice... In this case so it looks like answer is plausible at least: Q - "error ... Could not find the *Qt platform plugin*", A: "The *Qt platform plugin requires this library* to be installed." - so "Skip" is better choice in this case if you aren't an expert in Qt on Mac

Comment: Note that it was my subsequent edit that made the answer look plausible, @Alexei. (This edit also removes the post as an audit candidate in the future.)

Comment: @CodyGray did miss your edit... original version indeed looks more questionable... I'd likely trip over it too... also there is good chance I'd look at original post and realize that it's an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It is not at all obvious that a post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60276314/3) is a high-quality answer to the question that was being asked.
- Audits are supposed to be obvious.
- **Ergo, this was not a good audit.**

I have now [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60276314/4) the answer to make it a bit more obvious that it is attempting to provide an answer to the question that was asked. I've also removed noise and fixed the incorrect use of blockquote formatting. This edit should kick the post out of the running as an audit candidate. But even if it doesn't, it should ensure that others aren't tripped up on this again.

Do note that there is a simple trick to see if answers like this are actually audits: click the "link" link to open it in its original context. There, you can see that it has actually received a number of upvotes and must therefore be an audit. That would have allowed you to easily pass the audit. Then, you could fix the answer by editing it as I did.

Your review privileges *are* currently suspended for the next 4 days. However, that is unrelated to your having failed this bum audit. It's because [you misunderstood the purpose of the "Requires Editing" button in the Triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me). That button should only be used when you or some other third party can edit the question into shape. If the edits need to come from the original asker, or even after editing the question would still need to be closed, then "Requires Editing" is not the correct choice. Instead, you should vote "Unsalvageable".