# Is an early review-ban lift possible?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

I got banned from reviewing for this Triage review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25689373 
I decided for "Requires editing" which was a mistake as I can see now. My decision to choose "Requires editing" was that the question had serious code formatting problems (parts of the code have been in plain text), so I thought a user could fix this in the "Help and improvement" section. What I didn't notice is that the OP stated in his question that he would have attached the error logs which he didn't, so the question was unsalvageagble instead as only the OP would be able to fix that by adding the missing error logs.
My review ban is for 2 months, ending on May 29th, which is a long time. Because of this long time I think to have failed on more than just on this one question in Triage. It was the 2nd time I reviewed in the Triage queue as I'm aware that failing there could lead to getting banned from reviewing and want to avoid that. Therefore I'm taking care about the other review queues in general and avoided the Triage queue. I have to admit that my general understanding of the Triage improved within the last days by reading similar questions like mine as I know now that "Requires editing" is a problem when chosen wrongly.
I promise to be now more aware about that when reviewing Triage questions and would like to ask for an early review-ban lift as reviewing is at the moment my main occupation and keeps me occupied in a meaningful way while having to stay at home.

Comment: Please see the answer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me

Comment: Thanks, I already read this answer. It was very helpful for a better understanding of the Triage queue and the issues with "Requires editing".