# Answer is locked for a very long time but not permanently

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

I am asking this question out of interest and curiosity.

In the guide of [locked posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) it is mentioned that

> When a moderator locks a post they're required to select how long the lock should remain in place. The options are: 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, permanent.

But I have encountered an answer that is [Locked for 3626 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389149/7501501)!

How is this possible? I am not familiar with the moderators UI and maybe the options that are written in the guide are outdated.

Comment: FYI 3626 days are nearly 10 years, this question will be editable again at Saturday, March 9,  2030... XD

Comment: FYI that post is still editable, since it's only a *comment* lock. There are different types of post locks.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Why lock it for 10 years? Isn't a month or two sufficient? Isn't a week sufficient?

Comment: @SamuelLiew I didn't notice, thanks. Are you capable of locking the editing as well for any amount of time? If so why don't just make it the default for all moderators?

Comment: @S.S.Anne we don’t know how long the answer is going to be current. Locking it for a week would easily be too short.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Actually (though I can't comment on your answer, for obvious reasons) a **whole** millennium is 365242.5 days (on average). :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible because I have written a moderator-only userscript that allows me to input any custom duration of days when quick-locking posts with a custom post mod menu.

For example, this post is now comment-locked for 365000 days, a whole millennium.

[image: moderator userscript menu]

For more info about this userscript, see https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#additional-post-mod-actions-