# Why wasn't my review on triage/25860923 helpful?

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

To all who already have, or are considering downvoting this question:  please note this is *not* a generic question about how triage is broken, or why bans are seemingly inexplicably long. Rather this question is about why a *specific* review was flagged 'not helpful' and intends to seek an explanation for that *specific* review.  If there is a better forum for communicating (these types of questions) with moderators, please share.

**To moderators**: I'm looking for the rationale behind the disposition of [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25860923) and subsequent ban:

> Your review on triage/25860923 wasn't helpful. Please review the history of the post and consider which action would achieve that outcome more quickly. Come back on May 1 at 7:36 to continue reviewing.

The question of interest has been closed with the following explanation:

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers.

Here's a history of triage:

> Thanks! The consensus is: this post Looks OK.
>
> Please remember to upvote clear, useful, well-researched questions to encourage their authors and help answerers identify them!
>
> rtx13 reviewed this 16 hours ago: Looks OK
> razki reviewed this 18 hours ago: Requires Editing
> amin saffar reviewed this 18 hours ago: Looks OK
> alain.s reviewed this 20 hours ago: Looks OK

Comment: "Why my review on triage/25860923 wasn't helpful?" - because the question should've been closed.

Comment: Duplicate of [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving), along with several others for gold hammers to add

Comment: That question is a "do my work for me" request. Nothing more than a set of requirements and a demand someone write the code to fulfill them. It's also a trivial problem, and any competent programming could solve. These are not the kinds of questions we want to encourage on this site.

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate of "triage needs to be fixed..." question but rather "why this should be closed ("unsalvageble")... To which I provided my reasoning as answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that link, along with a few others, have been used as a canonical in several of these cases because they all tie back to the same root.

Comment: @Zoe I was really looking for the specifics in this case and Alexei offered those details.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me

Comment: the rules make no sense and the test question sometimes even less, take the ban, ignore it and do something nice instead of going to the morass that calls itself review

Comment: @nbk the rules make perfect sense... The question is essentially *"This is what I want, code it for me. Thanks!"* that's basically the definition of too broad

Comment: @Nick the rules for triage are hard to grasp because the line between a goog question and a bad is thin, gey and blurry. In Nysql there are a lot of qiestions with 1 close vote. Only one and we are 20 - 30 People who vote regularly,.even so, there are these questions that i find ok but somepne else not. So we as small band can't decude on ine rule for questions, how can that be for triage. where 3-5 people give their opinion to one question or answer(which is usually false selected) .and  now comes a moderator, whi has to sift through how many of these and decides you are wrong and ban you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a programming question to start with - "grep" is not "a tool primarily used by programmers". https://superuser.com/ may be better fit for this question (the OP would need to provide details where they're are stuck).

The question also shows zero research - it's just request to implement something without explaining where the OP has difficulties with their implementation.

Overall, the question should have been closed and hence voted "Unsalvageble" in the Triage queue. Possible options to close are

- either as "Off-topic - ask on Super User" (as non-programming question, but in the current state the question is also likely off-topic on Super User)
- "Needs details" (the question needs to be edited **by the original author** to show where they are stuck).
- custom - "Non-programming question about Grep usage". Probably would be most useful for the OP.

Please note that if you read the description of "grep" tag it should be clear that the question is not on-topic (highlight is mine):

> grep is a command-line text-search utility originally written for Unix. It uses regular expressions to match text, and is commonly used as a filter in pipelines. Use this tag only **if your question relates to programming using grep or grep-based APIs**. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting grep command-line options itself are off-topic.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, it is very helpful.  In prior reviews I struggled with flagging questions "off-topic", this definitely offers clearer guidance.