# The message box told me to come back in two days, but still nothing

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

At the time I got suspended from reviewing queues, due to 'No action needed' on a post that links to an answer, the message box told me to come back in two days. But how come after two days, nothing has changed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your review ban was reinstated on May 23rd, due to incorrect reviews on:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26193069
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26188430

In both of these cases, you chose the "Requires Editing" option, which was incorrect. There is no way that you, or I, or any other community member could edit those questions into compliance with [Stack Overflow's requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The only person who could fix those questions is the original asker, and that's *not* what the "Requires Editing" option means. If the edit needs to come from the original asker, then the question is "Unsalvageable" and needs to be flagged as "not suitable for this site".

More information can be found in these Q&A:

- [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me)
- [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)

Your current review ban has a duration of 32 days.