# So for a few weeks now I'm still "a user who can't review." How do I get back to being one who can?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage, review-suspension

So someone told me what I did wrong. And I did do that wrong thing. Is there such a thing as forgiveness in the SO universe? How do I get back to being able to review and make my small contribution to the running of the site?

Comment: For how long have you been suspended? What does the suspension message say?

Answer (score 8):

You chose the wrong option when reviewing all of the following posts in the Triage review queue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25743119
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25742488
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25738529
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25742559
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25742658

In particular, **you chose "Requires Editing" for questions that cannot possibly be edited to meet our guidelines by anyone other than the original author. "Requires Editing" means that anyone from the community can edit the question into shape. If the edit needs to come from the original author, then it's "Unsalvagable" (because it doesn't meet the site's standards and needs to be closed).**

When you go to https://stackoverflow.com/review in an attempt to review, you  should be presented with the following message:

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25742658 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community users (*like you*) are able to edit/format an *already answerable question* into a better shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead. If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see [*Getting banned from Triage reviews*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me) and [*How does the Triage queue work?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work)

which is attempting to explain the same thing to you that I did here, with the caveat that it only shows your most recently discovered incorrect review, not the whole history.

It will also tell you on that page that your suspension from reviewing lasts for 64 days. However, as the above-linked questions clarify, the duration has been intentionally set longer than punitive concerns would justify. Moderators are artificially lengthening review suspension durations now, in order to work around [a flaw in the site's UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving) that makes it less-than-obvious that you are even review banned and *certainly* doesn't make very clear the reason why. That was preventing review suspensions from serving their true pedagogical purpose. (The fact that you've been suspended from reviewing since April 1st, yet still don't have a clear understanding of *why* and how to improve your reviewing, is a perfect example.) The good news is two-fold:

1. Once you acknowledge that you've read our [guide to Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work) and understand the *proper* (albeit somewhat non-obvious) meaning of the "Requires Editing" option, your suspension will generally be commuted by a moderator (since the whole point really is to get your attention and educate you).
2. The site's designers and developers are currently working on major changes to the review queues that will fix the above-cited UI/UX problems.

Comment: Fine. I had assumed (incorrectly) that "Requires Editing" meant that the OP needed to edit the question. Now I know better. I will now read the guide to Triage. I'll be in touch.