# Suggestion: Tweak "Requires Editing" workflow for new reviewers to ensure they're doing it correctly

Tags: feature-request, triage, review-suspension

I'm new to reviewing and fairly quickly received my first-ever review suspension for incorrectly selecting "Requires Editing" during triage.  It was only 3 days, so not a big deal.

However, it appears that I am far from the only one who has problems incorrectly selecting this option -

Here's a screenshot from the accepted answer to the linked [Why was I suspended from reviewing for selecting “Requires Editing” in Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/why-was-i-suspended-from-reviewing-for-selecting-requires-editing-in-triage/389149#389149) question.
[image: screenshot of Requires Editing]

The highlighted sentence is a big red flag to me.  If most of your users (new reviewers in this case) are getting something wrong, it's more likely a system issue than a user issue.

What if, instead of suspending reviewers for getting it wrong even once, you gave new reviewers a chance to confirm that they understand what "Requires Editing" really means?

What I propose is that the first X times a new reviewer selects the "Requires Editing" option, they are presented with a "pop-up" (similar to the audit question pop-up) with text along the lines of:

**By selecting this option, are you saying that the question could be edited by the community (and not the OP) to make it acceptable?**

with the buttons

<kbd>**Yes, that's what I meant.**</kbd>

or

<kbd>**No, I didn't mean that.**</kbd>

This way, if they misunderstood the button (as I did), it gives them a chance to bail out before the selection becomes official while also reiterating the correct usage of that option.

Comment: I'm sure this has already been suggested, but I can't find the exact link. And if you almost **_never_** get suspended for making one mistake in the review queue.

Comment: @10Rep - if there was more than one mistake, would all of them be listed in the "You took incorrect action on the following task(s):" list?  For me, there's only one listed there.

Comment: No, they don't list all of them. IIRC they list the last review that you chose the wrong thing for. Sometimes Mods review ban you manually when they notice these. But I think it makes sense to unban you, since you weren't robo-reviewing and it's an honest mistake.

Comment: When you click the "(more)" link in the review tool box (under "We need your help separating questions into categories."), then you'll see that those buttons are explained there and there also an additional link to a detailed trial review explanation. So, your suggested change isn't needed, all the information are there, people just don't look for them.

Comment: @Tom If people just don't look for that information, as you say, why not bring the information to their attention front and center at the time they click the button?

Comment: @Tom I looked at that info and still got review banned for the same reason. It doesn't say anything about not hitting "Requires Editing" when the post isn't editable by fellow users.

Comment: @10Rep The description says *"Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing"*, so when ___you___ can't fix the question, then why do you assume some other non-op user can?

Comment: @Tom But it's not clear. Most people don't read those, and for those who do, they don't understand that only non-op users should be able to edit it. Hopefully you understand my point, which is that it needs to be more obvious.

Comment: This is a known issue (short version: everyone agrees with you that this is bad), and there is a plan to fix it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346902/improving-review-queues-design-overview-i-onboarding-and-updating-workflows

Comment: There was an answer there - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394506/8770 - that is probably a better solution than the one I proposed.  Knowing that there's a plan to fix the overall process is good enough for me (and I did leave some onboarding suggestions in that question).