# How am I reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

I recently crossed 2k rep (yay!) and therefore have access to three additional review queues.

Until now I did a lot of reviewing in "First Posts", "Late Answers" and "Triage" where I had the number of helpful vs. declined vs. disputed flags as a metric how good or bad I am reviewing. Are there any such metrics for the "Help & Improvement", "Low Quality Posts" or "Suggested Edits" queues?

I am aware that could see [my reviews in my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews) or go to the [history page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) of a queue. But the more I review the less manageable this lists become.

Comment: Note that in the LQP review queue, reviews where you recommend deletion don't appear in the Reviews part of your profile.

Comment: I do have a userscript that shows you the consensus in your review history: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508

Comment: @rene Thank you for your very useful script.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. By now, you should (hopefully) be experienced enough to know if you're reviewing correctly or not.

If you're not sure, you may want to spend some more time reviewing Suggested Edits and pressing the back button in your browser to see what other users are doing after you're done reviewing (which is what I do).

Also, I recommend not reviewing in the H&I queue unless you want to deal with a lot of crap that supposedly ["requires editing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372485/the-incorrect-usage-of-requires-editing-is-still-causing-problems-can-we-do-s).

If you give some more specific examples of where you're unsure if you did the right thing, I can review those reviews for you.

Comment: Thanks for your offer. I didn't have specific reviews in mind. Going back to single reviews to see the outcome was what I wanted to avoid. the script from rene is a big help here. As for H&I, I totally agree with you. I tried already to to some reviewing there but haven't found a single post which I could have edited.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser one of the things I do with H&I reviews that are bad is this: I find the triage review that got it there (from the post timeline) to judge and if it is an unanimous "requires editing" (so it never got a flag that would have put it in the CVQ) I flag the question for mod attention with a link to the triage review and ask for the reviewers to be informed of their wrong choice.

Comment: Alternatively, copy the URL and open it in an incognito window